# Insert data from XML file into MySql DB

Tags: php, mysql, xml, import

Hello i got problem with something, here it is 
i have to load xml file which has over 2000 properties, here you can find the structure of the file

http://admin.resales-online.com/live/Resales/Export/CreateXMLFeed.asp?U=RESALES@MOVE2S&P=KKPDRT6986NG&n=1

and i'm using the fallowing code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert Record</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
error_reporting(-1);

include ('config.php');

$url = "http://admin.resales-online.com/live/Resales/Export/XMLFeed.asp?U=RESALES@MOVE2S&P=KKPDRT6986NG&n=100";

try{
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO properties (`id`,`status_date`,`status`,`listed_date`,`last_updated`,`price`,`currency`,`country`,`province`) VALUES ';

foreach($xml->property as $property){
  $sql .= sprintf("\n",
    mysql_real_escape_string($property->id),
    mysql_real_escape_string($property->status_date),
    mysql_real_escape_string($property->listed_date),
    mysql_real_escape_string($property->last_updated),
    mysql_real_escape_string($property->price),
    mysql_real_escape_string($property->currency),
    mysql_real_escape_string($property->country),
    mysql_real_escape_string($property->province)
  );
}

$sql = rtrim($sql, ',') . ';';

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
  echo '<h1 style="color: red;">Error</h1><p>', mysql_error(), '</p>';
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

and i got this error

Error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Please if anyone knows what might be the problem answer me here :)

Thank you

Comment: The `mysql_*` list of functions is **deprecated**, please consider using `MySQLi` or `PDO` objects in your code. Otherwise you risk your code breaking when your version of PHP is upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

This is the format for an INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Where are your opening and closing parentheses for VALUES?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the values in the query are missing single quotes, and you're missing the opening and closing parenthesis. The proper syntax for an INSERT is:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

Yours will look more like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES value1, value2, value3
```

The easiest way to debug is to echo out your `$sql` varaible so you can see what it looks like so you can quickly spot obvious errors.

Comment: Well i changed something $sql .= sprintf("\n(%s)" in the code above is without $s now when i'm trying to echo the sql it shows this NSERT INTO properties (`id`) VALUES (R188242)..

Comment: and the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(R188246) (R188293) (R188310) (R188314) (R188318) (R188329) (R188349) (R188393) ' at line 3

Comment: but when i made the id from the database as int than the code worked for id and then it added to the database with number from 1 to 100 but when i changed to string now i can't add them.. something is wrong with the string i think

Comment: Int types will work without quotes, but strings need to be wrapped in quotes.